# regex: Why this negative lookahead doesn't work?

Tags: regex

I have text like this

```
real:: a
real :: b
real c
```

now I want to match the those real without `::` followed, and in this case, I want to match only the 3rd real. so I tried regex with lookahead

```
real\s*(?!::)
```

But this matches

```
real :: b
real c
```

For `\s*` means zero or more `\s`, why `real :: b` is being matched?

**update**

Thanks to Wiktor Stribiżew. Using regex101 debugging tool. We can find `backtrack` makes thing complicated.

I came up with another task that is similar but I can't solve

```
real (xx(yy)) :: a
real (zz(pp)):: b
real (cc(rr)) c
```

again, I want to match `real (cc(rr))` which is without `::` following.

```
real\s*\(.*?\)+(?!\s*::)
```

This is what I tried, but failed. Look into regex debug, it is also due to backtrack. But how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to put the `\s*` into the lookahead:

```
real(?!\s*::)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rW3wT8/1)

The `real\s*(?!::)` matches `real` because the `real` matches `real`, then the `\s*` matches 0 or more whitespaces, then the lookahead fails the match at the `::` **and the engine backtracks**, that is, it frees the space matched with `\s*` and tries to re-match the string. Since the `\s*` can match an empty string, the `real` before `:: b` gets matched.

See the [*regex debugger* scheme at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qY8dW5/1) showing what is going on behind the scenes:

[image]

Comment: Ok, but can you explain why my regex fail?

Comment: I added the explanation why the `\s*` outside the lookahead matches the second case and added the graph from regex101 illustrating the process.

Comment: @user15964  The assertion is a `Negative Lookahead Assertion`. This means that it asserts that the contents do no appear immediately following where it is placed.

Comment: Yes, alsom just note that if you used `real\s+(?!::)`, you would not match the second case, BUT it would catch the `real` if it were followed with 2 or more spaces with `::` - the backtracking would do its job the same as above.

Comment: Wow, I actually tried regex101 before. But I missed the debugger tool! Thank you very much for showing this, very useful!

Comment: Hi, Wiktor Stribiżew. I add another case which I can't solve, would you like to see it?

Comment: Almost left for a wlak with kids. Try [`real(?!.*?::)`](https://regex101.com/r/rW3wT8/2). You must allow 0+ chars before the `::` *inside* the lookahead, else backtracking will still make matching the unnecessary `real` possible.