# Regex negative look ahead not giving desired result

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, regex-lookarounds

I am having two strings as written below:

```
6015603 06/12/2017 06/12/2017 02:45:28 PM - BIL/001347764403/LOAN/NSP CR  20,000.00  8,381.002 S 6156702 06/12/2017 06/12/2017

6015603 06/12/2017 06/12/2017 - BIL/001347764403/LOAN/NSP CR  20,000.00  8,381.002 S 6156702 06/12/2017 06/12/2017
```

and a regular expression like below:

```
[0-9]+\s+[0-9]{2}[\/][0-9]{2}[\/][0-9]{4}\s+[0-9]{2}[\/][0-9]{2}[\/][0-9]{4}\s*(?![0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}\s*(AM|PM)).*?(?=([0-9]+\s*[0-9]{2}[\/][0-9]{2}[\/][0-9]{4}+\s+[0-9]{2}[\/][0-9]{2}[\/][0-9]{4})|\\Z)
```

As you can see I have used negative look ahead to avoid time

```
(?![0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}\s*(AM|PM))
```

but when I am running the pattern matching both strings are matching. I want the first string to be ignored. What is wrong here that I am doing?

Comment: Is your language escaping the backslashes?  You want a string literal. Or double backslashes each time you want one for the regex

Comment: Well I am using java. I just made it presentable in general regex irrespective of any language. In my code I am using escape characters for example \s+ is obviously \\s+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add a `(?!.*?\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s*[AP]M)` negative lookahead after matching the first date:

```
^\d+\s+\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s+\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}(?!.*?\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s*[AP]M).*?(?=(\d+\s*\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s+\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})|$)
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eDcGqB/2).

The lookahead will fail the match altogether if, after the first date and any 0+ chars, as few as possible, there is a time substring matching the  `\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s*[AP]M` pattern.

I also added the start of string/line `^` anchor, replaced all `[0-9]` with `\d` (it is shorter), `[\/]` to `/` (regexps in Java do not use regex delimiters hence no need escaping `/` which is not a special regex metacharacter), shrank `(AM|PM)` to `[AP]M` to decrease grouping overhead, and replaced `\Z` with `$`, but if you meant the end of string and never a line, you may use your `\Z` anchor.

Note that in Java, you will need to escape each backslash in the above string.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, your suggestions are valuable. I think these will make my regex compilation faster. :)

Comment: @manish Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution, I was not including \s* in negative look ahead. It is working as desired after including it.

The wrong one was:

```
\s*(?![0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}\s*(AM|PM))
```

and the correct one is:

```
(?!\s*[0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}\s*(AM|PM))
```

I took the answer reference from following thread:
[regex: Why this negative lookahead doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38573177/regex-why-this-negative-lookahead-doesnt-work)

Comment: Please also consider upvoting my answer if it proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).